# export SVG from OSM server maps

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have an Open Map Street Server hosting some maps, and I'm using leaflet to see the coordinates in my web-app.
I am trying to export the data in a HTML file and I'm trying to couple every point with a snapshot of the map and a marker at the centre of if.

I won't have any connection so I need to store the data in a folder and link it to an img tag maybe. Do you know any way to retrieve a PNG centered to a specific point from the locally hosted OSM server?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can get a tile in `PNG` or `SVG` format if you know border latitude and longitude making responce to these Url:

```
https://render.openstreetmap.org/cgi-bin/export?bbox=" + lat1 + long1 + lat2 + long2 + "&scale=yourSake&format=png;
```

Lat2Long1   Lat2Long2

Lat1Long1   Lat1Long2

You can find a simple example of these loader written in C# here:
[Github](https://github.com/andr1312e/Russia-Tiles-Server/tree/main/Program%20For%20Making%20Tiles%20From%20OSM%20to%20Mine%20format/Map%20Loader/5/MapDowloader5)